# What is the difference between Filters and Windowing?

Tags: filters, window-functions

I'm finding some difficulties to understand the difference between [Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29), and [Windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

accoriding to my understanding both filters and window functions will make changes to the input signal parameters, according to wiki,

**Filter:**

`a filter is a device or process that removes from a signal some unwanted component or feature`

**Windowing:**

`a window function (also known as an apodization function or tapering function[1]) is a mathematical function that is zero-valued outside of some chosen interval.`

---

What I'm trying to understand is this,

1. Where do we use these windowing functions & Filters in practical world?
2. Do I need to use both for better signal quality, if so which one come first(`Filters` => `Window` or `Window` => `Filters`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters and windows complement each other, in a way. This is due to the convolutional lemma of the fourier transform.

Let me expand on that. A filter would be a convolution of a signal with another. In a technical sense, a window has a fixed (supposedly short) size and is seen as "cutting out" a short part of the signal. Often, a DFT would follow.

In the fourier domain, convolution and point-wise multiplication trade places, so a convolution in the time domain is a pw. multiplication in the fourier domain and vice-versa.

A filter scales the spectrum with a known frequency response. A window will filter the spectrum instead.

Filters and window functions often (but not always) have different design goals. For example, in a filter you would have rather large bandwidths. Windows percieved as useful have a small bandwidth (often, just a few samples). You can talk about both kinds in the same terms, you just have to remember that both are used in different contexts.